# How to set and track a variable in the global scope using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to track the state of a drop-down menu using JS. I want to listen for a mouseover target and if the menu is open, I want to prevent the showing of a modal / pop-up.

I'm listening for the mouseover event like so:

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", Menu.menuHandler, true);
```

And I have a `menuHandler` function that set the variable like so:

```js
var menuOpen; // trying to set global variable?
export function menuHandler(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("dropdown-item")) { // Class I'm listening for
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menuOpen = false;
  }
  return menuOpen;
  // I have tried return window.menuOpen
}
```

Lastly, in a completely separate file, I'm trying to grab the value of `menuOpen` to prevent the popup from showing of a user has the popup open, but I keep getting the value of `undefined` when I `console.log(menuOpen)`

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like `menuOpen` is only assigned a value once you've hovered over the menu.  You could possibly set it to false to start with.

Comment: I tried setting the value to false, still returned undefined.

Comment: If you really want to use the global scope (there are usually other ways to share information that are safer) and since your code is not in the global scope (otherwise it would've worked as you intended) you should use `window.menuOpen` all over - drop the var declaration and assign to window.menuOpen

Comment: Ah that worked perfectly. What other ways would you recommend sharing information between files that are safer?

Comment: I suggest that you did not set the global `menuOpen`, and your `var menuOpen` is within some function (not in global scope).

Comment: @Sackadelic it really depends on how your code is structured, where is this function defined and where you use the variable, to find some object that is shared between those contexts.

Comment: Okay, I will certainly research. You can submit an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!